# Force images to overflow in table cells

Tags: html, css

How to force images to overflow in table cells without expanding the cells?

## EDIT:

Sorry, I'll provide some more information. This is the table:

```
<table class="content">
    <col width="200px" />
    <col width="560px" />
    <col width="200px" />
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="logo"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.logo
{
    height: 120px;
    background: url('img/wallpaper.png') center;
}
```

I thought there would be a simple solution...

Comment: *Very low quality:* What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: Well, I've tried nesting tables withing tables, which works, but I'd like to know how to force images to overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use an `<img>` tag instead of a background image, you could remove it from document flow with `position: absolute;`

**html**

```
<td class="logo">
    <img src="img/wallpaper.png">
</td>
```

**css**

```
.logo img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

This will let the image overflow the cell, but creates other side-effects you would need to deal with.

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/QMNRp/1/

Comment: This works great, but it creates x-scroll, which I don't need. I actually realized that I would probably need to attach the logo image to the body wallpaper. I'm trying expand the logo image in x direction without creating x-scroll etc.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for an element's `background` to escape into the foreground. This isn't possible. An element's background can only be as large as the element itself.

To make the `.logo` image the same dimensions as the containing cell you could make use of the [`background-size` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size), but this [isn't supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) in older browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Set Static Width to td's and set `overflow` to `visible` and `text-wrap:nowrap;` or `word-break` to `keep all` for text in tables

```
td{
width:100px;
max-width:100px;
overflow:visible
text-wrap:nowrap;  //for text
word-break:keep-all;  // for text
}
```

Comment: @xec please check the answer's time compared with the question's edit. Downvoting an answer because it no longer applies **after** the question was edited is pretty unfair.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly You're right, i would remove the downvote, except this answer wouldn't help with preventing a table cell from stretching, background-image or otherwise.

Comment: @xec Just for reference this *would* work for overflowing the width, but not the height: http://jsfiddle.net/erKGm/

Comment: @JamesDonnelly aha! it is the max-width that does the trick. it should be better reflected in the answer text. i retract my previous statement and apologize for the downvote but SO apparently prevents me from doing so unless the answer is edited.